# Ajax POST request to ODATA service throws Invalid HTTP status code 501

Tags: ajax, wcf, http, post, odata

I have the following code which I wish to use for inserting a record into an entity of an ODATA service. 
The post request throws a XMLHttpRequest cannot load Invalid HTTP status code 501.

Apparently GET request works fine. Can anyone suggest a way to find out the problem ? Does my WCF Service has a problem ?

```
            var data = { application_id: 777 , user_id: 'test' };
            var data = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                datatype: 'json',
                url: oDataURL + 'application_admins',
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
                    account = data.d;
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi, I test your code. It seems work fine. 
you can find my test codes at [Here](https://github.com/xuzhg/WebApiSample/commit/bd85bea91aefc4f48d676cab664b4ced7e801bbf)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @SamXu. I checked my code and there are some problems with the data base mappings. So sometimes the request is not completed.